# How do I recover "discarded" files using Pages?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, pages

I was trying to save a file on my Mac and it said

> The document could not be saved. 
>   You don't have permission

I have papers to write and recover because they decided to delete themselves

How do I fix this "You don't have permission" error when using Pages on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the System and or User permissions need cleaning/Repair

To fix the System level permissions:

Open Disk Utility and repair the permissions.

To fix the user level permissions

Restart while holding the cmd-r.

The select reset password (you will NOT be resenting the password)

Instead use the restore ACL's on that screen,